# What do I pass as arguments when using rust-protobuf?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I am trying to follow the [instructions](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/tree/master/protoc-rust) to generate Rust protobuffer files:

> ## API to generate .rs files
>
> API to generate `.rs` files to be used e. g. [from
>   build.rs](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/blob/master/protobuf-test/build.rs).
>
> Example code:
>
> ```
> extern crate protoc_rust;
>
> protoc_rust::run(protoc_rust::Args {
>     out_dir: "src/protos",
>     input: &["protos/a.proto", "b.proto"],
>     includes: &["protos"], }).expect("protoc");
> ```
>
> And in `Cargo.toml`:
>
> ```
> [build-dependencies]
> protoc-rust = "1.4"
> ```
>
> Note this API requires `protoc` command present in `$PATH`. Although
>   `protoc-gen-rust` command is not needed.

There is no explicit documentation for what is to be passed for these arguments.  The first one (`out_dir`) is pretty obviously the directory to generate files in.  `input` looks like a list of `.proto` files to use for generation.  In this example, the first has a directory, while the second doesn't.  Do I need to pass a directory for each, or just the first? `includes` is really puzzling me.  Is this a list of folders to look in?  If I add `protos` here, can I omit it for the elements of `input`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the source code ([source](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/blob/master/protoc-rust/src/lib.rs#L16)) you will see this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Args<'a> {
    /// --lang_out= param
    pub out_dir: &'a str,
    /// -I args
    pub includes: &'a [&'a str],
    /// List of .proto files to compile
    pub input: &'a [&'a str],
}
```

So the meaning of these arguments is:

`out_dir`: the location of generated files

`includes` (`-I`): location where protoc will search for imports ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing-definitions))

`input`: list of `.proto` files to compile